Applying the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem to an example
I know the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem:
If $X$ is compact and $\mathcal{A}$ is a closed subalgebra of $C(X)$ such that:

$1 \in \mathcal{A}$
for $x,y \in X$ with $x \neq y$, there exists f$ \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $f(x) \neq f(y)$
if $f \in \mathcal{A}, then \overline{f} \in \mathcal{A}$

then $\mathcal{A}$ is dense in $C(X)$.
Now I want to use this theorem to solve some Corollary/Exercise.
For example:
Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are compact Hausdorff spaces and $f \in C(X \times Y)$. Show that for each $\epsilon >0$, there exist functions $f_1,...,f_n \in C(X)$ and $g_1,...,g_n \in C(Y)$ such that
$|f(x,y)- \sum_{k=1}^n f_k(x)g_k(y)|\leq \epsilon$ for all $(x,y) \in X \times Y$.
My Approach:
My main "Problem" is that I am not very familiar with the concept of an Algebra. So I want to do it with as much detail as possible. To start here is the Definition of algebra and subalgebra.
Definition (Algebra):
Let $A$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{K}$. Then $A$ is an algebra if there exists a multiplication operation $A \times A \rightarrow A$, $(f,g) \mapsto f \cdot g $that is bilinear, commuting and there exists a unit $1 \in A$ such that $f \cdot 1= 1 \cdot f=f$.
A subalgebra of $A$ is a vector subspace of $A$, which is closed under said multiplication operation and contains the unit.
To apply the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem to the example I, my compact set is $X \times Y$.
My algebra $\mathcal{A}$ is the set of polynomials $P(X \times Y) $.  And the multiplication operation is the multiplication of polynomials. Obviously, $P(X \times Y)$ is closed under multiplication with a polynomial.
Then the unit $1: (x,y) \mapsto (1,1)$ is in $P(X \times Y)$.
Let $a:=(x_1,y_1),b:=(x_2,y_2) \in X \times Y$ and $a \neq b$, then for $f:=x \in P(X \times Y)$, $f(a)\neq f(b)$.
And finally since for any $f \in P(X \times Y)$ $\overline{f}(x,y)=f(\overline{(x,y)})$, $\overline{f} \in P(X \times Y).$
Finally, I can apply the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem and get that $P(X \times Y)$ is dense in $C(X \times Y)$, which in fact means that for $f \in C(X \times Y)$ and  $\epsilon >0$ there do exists functions $f_1,...,f_n \in C(X)$ and $g_1,...,g_n \in C(Y)$ such that
$|f(x,y)- \sum_{k=1}^n f_k(x)g_k(y)|\leq \epsilon$ for all $(x,y) \in X \times Y$.
Questions:
Is my solution correct? (I have noticed that in the exercise it is mentioned that $X,Y$ are Hausdorff, but I did not use this property.)
I thought of using polynomials as the algebra because I know that polynomials are dense in the set of continuous functions, so this should surely work. But if I am working on an example where I do not have that information, how do I choose the algebra?

$X$ and $Y$ are just compact Hausdorff spaces, not subsets of $\mathbb{C}$, so “polynomials” don’t make sense. Instead, consider the subalgebra of $C(X \times Y)$ consisting of all elements of the form $\sum_{k=1}^n f_kg_k$ where $f_k \in C(X)$, $g_k \in C(Y)$.

@DavidGao Okay. So let $\mathcal{A}:={\sum_{k=1}^n f_kg_k : f_k \in C(X), g_k\in C(Y)}$. Then $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space. Also, $\mathcal{A} \subset C(X \times Y)$. But what is then the multiplication operation so that $\mathcal{A}$ really is an algebra? I assume the multiplication operation to be $m:(f_1,..,f_n,g_1,...,g_n) \mapsto \sum_{k=1}^nf_kg_k$? Is that correct?

It is a subalgebra of $C(X \times Y)$. The multiplication is simply inherited from $C(X \times Y)$.

@DavidGao What do you mean by that? I am not really following.

I’m not sure what’s the confusion here. Any $\sum_{k=1}^n f_kg_k$ is a continuous function on $X \times Y$. Just multiply them as you would two continuous functions (i.e., pointwise). This is just what being a subalgebra of $C(X \times Y)$ means. If you find this confusing I’d suggest going back to read more on this topic, especially the definitions.

@DavidGao I think I got it now. Thank you!

In that Case, condition 2. of the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem follows by "Partition of Unity" (or Urysohn Lemma). And condition 3 follows by the definition of $\mathcal{A}$.

That is correct, yes.

As a remark, although your statement involving the Stone-Weierstrass theorem is valid, this is not how you typically state the theorem. You typically either omit the assumption that $\mathcal{A}$ is closed in $C(X)$ or instead state that $\mathcal{A} = C(X)$, because if $\mathcal{A}$ is closed and dense in $C(X)$, it is equal to $C(X)$. If you assume that $\mathcal{A}$ must be closed, then you need to know that the closure of a subalgebra of $C(X)$ is again a subalgebra of $C(X)$ in order to apply the Stone-Weierstrass theorem. This follows from the continuity of the algebraic operations.
Your definition of an algebra appears to be what is usually called a commutative unital algebra. Typically, it is not assumed in the definition of an algebra that the multiplication operation is commutative and it is not assumed that the multiplication operation has a unit element. The current definition you are using makes the first condition of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem redundant.
It is not clear what the set $P(X\times Y)$ you are discussing is, since there is no obvious way to define polynomials on a given compact Hausdorff space. Instead, you can consider the set $\mathcal{A}$ whose elements are finite sums of elements $h\in C(X\times Y)$ where there are $f\in C(X)$ and $g\in C(Y)$ such that $h(x,y) = f(x)g(y)$ for all $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$. What you want to do is verify that $\mathcal{A}$ is a subalgebra of $C(X\times Y)$ which contains the constant functions, separates the points and is closed under conjugation. Then the desired result follows from the Stone-Weierstrass theorem. Also note that you need that $X\times Y$ is compact Hausdorff to apply the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, which is true as a product of Hausdorff topological spaces is Hausdorff and a product of compact topological spaces is compact, so this is one place where you need the assumption that $X$ and $Y$ are Hausdorff.
To show that $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under multiplication, take two elements of $\mathcal{A}$, which are of the form $\sum_{\alpha \in F_{1}} f_{\alpha}g_{\alpha}$ and $\sum_{\beta \in F_{2}} f_{\beta} g_{\beta}$ where $F_{1}$ and $F_{2}$ are finite sets with $\{f_{\gamma} : \gamma \in F_{1} \cup F_{2}\} \subseteq C(X)$ and $\{g_{\gamma} : \gamma \in F_{1} \cup F_{2}\} \subseteq C(Y)$. Then
\begin{align*}
\left( \sum_{\alpha \in F_{1}} f_{\alpha}g_{\alpha} \right) \left( \sum_{\beta \in F_{2}} f_{\beta} g_{\beta} \right) &= \sum_{\alpha \in F_{1}} \left( f_{\alpha} g_{\alpha} \left( \sum_{\beta \in F_{2}} f_{\beta} g_{\beta} \right) \right) \\
&= \sum_{\alpha \in F_{1}} \sum_{\beta \in F_{2}} f_{\alpha} g_{\alpha} f_{\beta} g_{\beta} \\
&= \sum_{(\alpha , \beta ) \in F_{1} \times F_{2}} (f_{\alpha}f_{\beta}) (g_{\alpha}g_{\beta}).
\end{align*}
As $F_{1} \times F_{2}$ is a finite set and as both $f_{\alpha}f_{\beta} \in C(X)$ and $g_{\alpha}g_{\beta} \in C(Y)$ for all $\alpha \in F_{1}$ and $\beta \in F_{2}$, $\left( \sum_{\alpha \in F_{1}} f_{\alpha}g_{\alpha} \right) \left( \sum_{\beta \in F_{2}} f_{\beta}g_{\beta} \right) \in \mathcal{A}$. It can be shown in a similar manner that $\mathcal{A}$ is a vector subspace of $C(X\times Y)$ containing the unit element and is closed under conjugation.
To show that $\mathcal{A}$ separates the points, let $(x_{1}, y_{1}), (x_{2}, y_{2}) \in X\times Y$ with $(x_{1}, y_{1}) \neq (x_{2}, y_{2})$. If $x_{1} \neq x_{2}$, as $X$ is Hausdorff and compact $X$ is normal. Note that this is another place where you need that $X$ is Hausdorff. By Urysohn's lemma there exists $f\in C(X)$ such that $f(x_{1}) = 1$ and $f(x_{2}) = 0$. Let $g$ be the constant function on $Y$. Then $h:X\times Y \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by $h(x,y) := f(x)g(y)$ is an element of $\mathcal{A}$ with $h(x_{1}, y_{1}) = 1$ while $h(x_{2}, y_{2}) = 0$. By an analogous argument involving applying Urysohn's lemma to $C(Y)$, which also uses that $Y$ is Hausdorff, if $y_{1} \neq y_{2}$, there is some $h\in C(X\times Y)$ such that $h(x_{1}, y_{1}) \neq h(x_{2}, y_{2})$. This shows that $\mathcal{A}$ separates the points. All conditions have been verified in order to apply the Stone-Weierstrass theorem and the desired result follows.
